# shell find - get folder name for current file

Tags: shell, find

I want to use exiftool to give serial numbers to jpg-files.
The files are contained in sub directories to a main directory
What can I replace FOLDER_OF_CURRENT_FILE with to achieve this?

find . -type f -name "*.jpg" -exec exiftool -SerialNumber=FOLDER_OF_CURRENT_FILE;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With find:

```
find . -mindepth 2 -type f \( -iname '*.jpg' -o -iname '*.jpeg' \) \
-exec sh -c '
    for path do
        dir=${path%/*}
        dir=${dir##*/}
        echo exiftool -overwrite_original -SerialNumber="${dir}" "$path"
    done' _ {} +
```

This is a dry run. You can run it, and view the command line to be executed. If it looks ok, remove `echo` to run for real.

- `-mindepth 2` must specified, unless you want `-SerialNumber=.`
- `-iname` means ignore case

Alternatively, it's possible to do this entirely with exiftool:

```
exiftool -r -overwrite_original '-SerialNumber<${directory; s=.*/==s;}' .
```

- `-r` is for recursive
- Exiftool allows attributes to be specified, and arbitrary perl code to be injected with them. So perl substitution can be used to remove everything up to the last directory. I used the `s` modifier (second s) to cover paths which might contain a new line.
- There's also `${directory;my @a=split m(/); $_ = $a[-1]}` which produces the same result (split path by slash in to an array, and use the last element)
- This modifies all supported file formats. To specify jpg files only, replace `.` with `-ext jpg -ext jpeg .`
- Obviously, `-overwrite_original` is optional, but running recursively might create many duplicate images otherwise